# C# POST to OAUTH2 with formdata

Tags: c#, json, post, ssis, httpwebresponse

I have used Chrome Advanced Rest Client (ARC) to get the access token for my API call.  I am now trying to take what I have working there and convert it to a POST call in my SSIS Script Component.

[image]

I have 4 values that I need to include in the data form section of the post.

grant_type = client_credentials

and our partner_id, client_id and client_secret.

How/where do I enter this information in my request?  Here is the code I have tried to use. I have another section that does a GET which works when I hard code the token.  I am trying to get this POST call to get a new token to use in the GET.

```
private TokenObject GetWebServiceToken(string wUrl)

{

    string grant_type = "client_credentials";
    string partner_id = "our partner_id";
    string client_id = "our client_id";
    string client_secret = "our encoded string";

    HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(wUrl);

    httpWReq.Method = "POST";

    httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    HttpWebResponse httpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();       

    TokenObject jsonResponse = null;


    try

    {

        //Get the stream of JSON

        Stream responseStream = httpWResp.GetResponseStream();

        //Deserialize the JSON stream

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))

        {   //Deserialize our JSON

            DataContractJsonSerializer sr = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TokenObject));

            jsonResponse = (TokenObject)sr.ReadObject(responseStream);

        }

    }

    //Output JSON parsing error

    catch (Exception e)

    {

        FailComponent(e.ToString());

    }

    return jsonResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request is just text encoded and formatted in a way similar to how query strings parameters are.

You should be able to create and send your request by replacing this part:

```
httpWReq.Method = "POST";

httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

HttpWebResponse httpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
```

With the following code:

```
var postData = "grant_type=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(grant_type);
postData += "&partner_id=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(partner_id);
postData += "&client_id=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(client_id);
postData += "&client_secret=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(client_secret);

var body = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

httpWReq.Method = "POST";
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWReq.ContentLength = body.Length;

using (var stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(body, 0, body.Length);
}

HttpWebResponse httpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse(); 

// response deserialization logic
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you use HttpClient?  I'm using something like the following to get a token ack from Salesforce.  The Json parsing is done by Json.net, but any json parser should suffice.

```
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"grant_type", "client_credentials"},
    {"client_id", "<your client id>"},
    {"client_secret", "<your secret>"},
    {"partner_id", "<your partner id>"}
});

using (var httpClient =  new HttpClient())
{
    var message = await httpClient.PostAsync("<your authorization url>", content);
    var responseString = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var obj = JObject.Parse(responseString);

    var oauthToken = (string)obj["access_token"];
    var serviceUrl = (string)obj["instance_url"];

    //more code to write headers and make an actual call
}
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly and it was extremely easy to implement. Thank you.